# BITMAP.bmBits format

Tags: winapi, bmp

Whats `BITMAP.bmBits` format? As I understand `BGR` but with some aligns (differs from size?). Please explain how this aligns work and how convert bitmap to `RGBA` without aligns (empty space) properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the values of the rest of the structure. See the MSDN articles on [`CreateBitmap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`BITMAPINFOHEADER.biBitCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the details.

Each scan line (row of pixels) must be DWORD aligned with the padding calculated using somethign along the lines of:

```
ScanLineWidth = 3 - (((Width * BytesPerPixel) + 3) mod 4)
```

Other [examples](http://en.literateprograms.org/BMP_decoder_%28C%29#chunk%20def%3ascanline%20bytes%20calculation) [available](http://www.powerbasic.com/support/pbforums/showthread.php?t=42591).

32-bit per pixel data is already DWORD aligned.

Comment: I have 24bit per pixel data (BGR). What is scan line? I cant understand logic of this aligning. Some tests (c - color bytes, [image size])                                  c             [1 x 1]                                                          
c 0 c         [1 x 2]
c c c         [1 x 3]
c 0 c 0 c 0 c [1 x 4]
c c 0 0 c c   [2 x 2]

Comment: A scan line is a single row of pixels. If it's 24-bit per pixel with 2 columns, it would be 6 bytes of data then padded to 8 bytes (DWORD alignment, divisable by 4) for each row. If it was 4 columns, it would be an even 12 bytes which is already DWORD aligned (divisable by 4).

Comment: So what algorithm I should use to convert BGR (aligned) BITMAP to RGB pixel array (without align)?

Comment: So I understood correctly that pixel raw is aligned by Width % 4 bytes?

Comment: Almost. Here are some examples:
http://www.powerbasic.com/support/pbforums/showthread.php?t=42591
http://en.literateprograms.org/BMP_decoder_(C)#chunk def:scanline bytes calculation